# Device login trouble

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, devise

I have such modal window in my standart layout (default is hiden)

```
.sign_in_modal
      .top
        %h4
          Вход для пользователей
        = link_to "Закрыть", "#", :remote => true, :class => "close-link"
      .left
        .input-area
          = form_tag new_user_session_path do
            = email_field_tag :email, nil, :placeholder => "Ваш e-mail", :required => "true", :class => "input"
            = password_field_tag :password, nil, :placeholder => "Ваш пароль", :required => "true", :class => "input"
            = check_box_tag "Запомнить меня",'user[remember_me]', true
            %span
              Запомнить?
          .button-area
            = submit_tag "Вход", :class => "sign_in_link", :id => "submit"
      .right
        %h4
          или
        %p
          Войти при помощи:
          = link_to image_tag('facebook.png'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)
          = link_to image_tag('vk.png'), url_for(user_omniauth_authorize_path(:vkontakte))
        %h4
          Преимущества:
```

my js looks like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".close-link").click(function() {
    $(".sign_up_modal").hide();
    $(".sign_in_modal").hide();
    $('.hide').hide("slow");
  });

  $(".sign_in_link").click(function() {
      console.log("eue123ueu");
      $('.hide').fadeTo("slow",0.8);
      $(".sign_in_modal").show();
      $(".sign_in_modal").center(); 
  }); 
});
```

But when i fill form, and click button, nothing happens. How to do that, if i fill form and click submit button, devise authorization log's me?

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors? Does it work if you remove the javascript click event?

Comment: @Beerlington js - no errors, if i done this as usual, not modal window, i still get nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could see from your code you have error in HAML indentation. Your `submit_tag` is outside `form_tag` cause of `.button_area` block.

Just move both of them to the right to correct indents.

Comment: Which method do you mean: devise controller method to login user or js function binded to click on `$(".sign_in_link")`? Does js console logs  `"eue123ueu"` message?

Comment: @brabertaser1992  You are welcome. Feel free to ask any questions. Even in Russian. 8)